# Getting error "cannot import name 'run_cli' from 'robot'" with Gitlab CI Runner

Tags: python, linux, robotframework, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a robot command like `python -m robot --include staging_lp_items` which is run perfectly in my system.

When trying to run this with GitLab runner (as a stage script) in a server machine, this error is shown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/robot/__main__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from robot import run_cli
ImportError: cannot import name 'run_cli' from 'robot' (/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/robot/__init__.py)
```

I also to make sure of installing robot, return the `pip list` before main script and `robot` is installed on the server environment as well as other requirements in `requirements.txt` file.
Here is the system config:

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="11"
VERSION="11 (bullseye)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bullseye
```

GitLab Yaml:

```
stages:
  - build
  - build_branch
  - test

variables:
  REGISTRY_IMAGE: ${CI_REGISTRY}/qa/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}
  GIT_IMAGE: ${CI_REGISTRY}/qa/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}


build:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  before_script:
    - docker login -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} ${CI_REGISTRY}
  script:
    - echo image name $REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    - docker build -t $REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG .
    - docker push $REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
  rules:
    - when: manual


build_branch:
  image: docker:latest 
  stage: build_branch
  before_script:
    - docker login -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD} ${CI_REGISTRY}
  script:
    - echo project image is ${GIT_IMAGE}
    - docker build --build-arg CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=master -t $GIT_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME .
    - docker push $GIT_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  rules:
    - when: manual
  allow_failure: true

run_test:
  image: $GIT_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME
  stage: test
  script:
    - cat /etc/os-release
    - chmod +x ./.deploy/run-test.sh
    - ./.deploy/run-test.sh
  rules:
    - when: manual
  allow_failure: false
```

There are 3 stages, `build` and `build_branch` work fine. The last one is the main stage that I have a problem with it. This stage will run (eval) the `run-test.sh` that has a simple python-robotframework command I mentioned before.

Python Version : 3.9

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.9
ARG CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME=master
COPY . .
RUN pip install [Repository]
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: You may want to add the .yml file and the versions of the python on the system and brief about the problem what are your trying to do.

Comment: `is installed on the server environment` It's the same version? Are you using shell executor? Is it installed inside the environment that giltab-runner is runnning? Etc.

Comment: @Dev Added `gitlab-ci.ym`l on the question

Comment: @KamilCuk Yeah they're the same, version. You can see the yaml file which I explained exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: `image: $GIT_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME` Are they the same version within that docker image? What gitlab-runner executor are you using? If you build your docker image locally and run your script within there, do you get the same error? Please post the Dockerfile content - please post _all_ the files needed to reproduce the problem, ie. an [MCVE]. If you download the docker image from gitlab container registry and run your script manually in it, do you get the same error? Etc...

Comment: @KamilCuk I've added Dockerfile. Packages are the same version inside the image and my system. It runs without problem in the system.

Comment: How are you checking package versions? What is `[repository]`? Does `docker run -ti --rm ${CI_REGISTRY}/qa/${CI_PROJECT_NAME} python -c 'from robot import run_cli` work? Does your local docker image has the same SHA that the image on gitlab server in container registry?

Comment: @KamilCuk I just write it like this to don't show my credential and repository address. 
It seems that your python command is not correct
`python -c 'from robot import run_cli'`

Comment: What's in requirements.txt for robot ?

Comment: Does `docker run -ti --rm ${CI_REGISTRY}/qa/${CI_PROJECT_NAME} python -c 'from robot import run_cli'` work from your shell, where the image `${CI_REGISTRY}/qa/${CI_PROJECT_NAME}` is the same image as in gitlab registry, as in it has the exact same SHA? When you build the docker file locally, does the same command with your local docker SHA image work? What does it output? Yes - there is missing `'` on the end, is it worth noting a comment? And, you figured it out - so did you run it within the docker container context?

Comment: @KamilCuk that command fails with this error `the input device is not a TTY`
I'm working on your other suggestions

Comment: Remove `-ti` flag - and try again.

Comment: I can reproduce with just `docker run -ti --rm python:3.9 sh -c 'pip install robot && python -c "from robot import run_cli"'` Are you __sure__ there's `run_cli` in `robot-20071211`? __Please__ post an [MCVE] - please include your requirements.txt file.... Please add all the steps that you used to make sure there are same versions of packages on your system and inside the container. What gitlab-runner executor are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your requirementst.txt is invalid. You have `robot` there https://pypi.org/project/robot/, while the library that you want to use is named  `robotframework` https://pypi.org/project/robotframework/.

Rename `robot` to `robotframework` in your requirements.txt.

Comment: I have both `robot` and `robotframework` in my requirements.txt.

Comment: Then remove robot and uninstall it.

Comment: Thank you KamiCuk. The problem is resolved by removing `robot` from requirements.